# Catlina Security: Does root need permissions?

Tags: catalina, security, permission, privacy, root

Consider the new privacy system in Catalina. E.g. disk access, cam, mic, input etc. Does an application run as root need such permissions or is everything inherently granted?

Comment: Is this a general question or are you asking about a specific application? It is an application you installed or something you developed on your own? Please edit the question to clarify that.

Comment: Why specializing if the question can be answered in general? Well distrusting Apple makes no sense, so well yes non system software. I see no point in differentiating own and others software. I see not point in differentiating at all. Maybe I am missing something though.

Comment: This site focuses on getting verifiable answers to practical problems, and the answers in your case will be different depending on the actual problem you have. Are you using an application which seems to have access issues (so the answers should focus on that), are you interested in understanding how things work in general (so answers should point you to the available documentation on the topic), are you a developer struggling with sandboxing and code signing, etc.

Comment: To clarify things a bit...it’s what you asked that doesn’t make sense.  Everything you referred to, disk access, mic, cam, etc., are macOS resources that *applications* must now be granted permission to use.  To allow/disallow those apps from access things depends on whether or not you have the permission to grant those rights.  Asking if *root* has inherent permission to everything isn’t related and technically, no, it doesn’t

Comment: Adding... why does this application need to run as root in any case?  This is almost always a bad idea... I'd ask what problem you think you're solving.

Comment: @Allan answers the question. Its not a dedicated practical case I am talking about. I guess I would have asked on SO otherwise. It is a general question. I want to understand the Catalina security system. A super user is able to change permissions, does it make sense then force him to grant himself access to resources?

Comment: Thats a good topic - the Catalina Security System - and would definitely get upvotes, but by the same token too overly broad for the format of this site.  Each topic has been addressed in one, way, shape or form, but maybe we can find a way to re-ask the question so it’s both practical and comprehensive?  Let me know...we can start a chat

Answer (score 0):

Even if an application can run as root, in macOS Catalina and some previous versions, SIP prevents root from making changes to certain protected files. As of macOS Catalina, system files are stored in a separate volume that is mounted read-only. As for the privacy settings, applications even if they run as root must ask and get permission from the user in order to get access to Full Disk Permissions, Microphone, Camera, etc.. Note that this might differ in Macs with the Apple T2 Security chip. Also, as @nohillside mentioned, it is important to determine whether it is an application that you created or not because macOS' security features determine what an application can do and whether it can run by Code Signing. If it is an app that you developed that isn't signed or isn't on the App Store, then the permissions might be different. In general, every application must ask for permission before getting access.

Answer (score 0):

Root is basically no better than any admin account on Catalina.